# Bootstrap 4 not working popover offline

Tags: bootstrap-4

I have a problem about popover offline, i dont know what is the proper javascript link in bootstrap 4

```
 <div class="container">
  <h3>Popover Example</h3>
  <a href="#" title="Header" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="top" data-content="Content">Top</a>
  <a href="#" title="Header" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom" data-content="Content">Bottom</a>
  <a href="#" title="Header" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="left" data-content="Content">Left</a>
  <a href="#" title="Header" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="right" data-content="Content">Right</a>
</div>
```

here is the bootstrap javascript

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();   
});
</script>


<script src="js/bootstrap.bundle.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Do you have jQuery loaded? You need it. Also remove excess versions of Bootstrap JS. Just keep `bootstrap.bundle.min.js`.

Answer (score 1):

1. use jQuery script before bootstrap. Bootstrap js requires jQuery.
2. Remove all bootstrap 4 js except `<script src="js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`;